# Prevent click on JPlayer Seekbar

Tags: scrollbar, jplayer

I have an audio clip that plays through once and then the 'Play' button is disabled so that it can't be played again. The only problem is the scrollbar is clickable so that the user can go back to the beginning or forwards which is not the desired process as they should only be able to play it once.

Is there a way of preventing a user from clicking on the blue progress bar as per the image below?

Thanks

[image: JPlayer Scrollbar]

Answer (score 0):

There is a div on top of the progressbar with the the class "jp-seek-bar".
It is this div which makes the progressbar scrollable.

```
<div class="jp-progress">
    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So you simply need to remove this div. The progress itself will still be visible.

```
<div class="jp-progress">        
    <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>        
</div>
```

Another solution is to unbind the event-listener binded to the jp-seek-bar div.